# Retrieve parent and child object with InvokeRetrieve()

Tags: ampscript

I'm having trouble retrieving EmailSendDefiniton object with its Email.

```
VAR @oid, @rresd, @sfpesd, @list1

SET @oid = RequestParameter("oid")

SET @rresd = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rresd, "ObjectType", "EmailSendDefinition")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "CreatedDate")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "Name")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "DeduplicateByEmail")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendDefinitionList")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "EmailSubject")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendLimit")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendWindowOpen")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendWindowClose")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "Email")

SET @sfpesd = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfpesd, "Property", "ObjectID")
SetObjectProperty(@sfpesd, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfpesd, "Value", @oid)
SetObjectProperty(@rresd, "Filter", @sfpesd)

SET @list1 = InvokeRetrieve(@rresd)
```

This code doesn't work (@list returns 0 rows), however when I delete

```
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "Email")
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. I can retrieve Email.ID and then create another request to retrieve Email object with that ID.

```
VAR @oid, @rresd, @sfpesd, @list1, @esdEmailID

SET @oid = RequestParameter("oid")

SET @rresd = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rresd, "ObjectType", "EmailSendDefinition")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "CreatedDate")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "Name")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "DeduplicateByEmail")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendDefinitionList")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "EmailSubject")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendLimit")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendWindowOpen")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "SendWindowClose")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rresd, "Properties", "Email.ID")

SET @sfpesd = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfpesd, "Property", "ObjectID")
SetObjectProperty(@sfpesd, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfpesd, "Value", @oid)
SetObjectProperty(@rresd, "Filter", @sfpesd)

SET @list1 = InvokeRetrieve(@rresd)

IF RowCount(@list1) != 1 THEN
    RaiseError("ERROR ID1", true)
ELSE
    SET SET @esdEmailID = Field(Field(Row(@list1, 1), "Email"), "ID")
ENDIF
```